# Can't play embedded private youtube playlists anymore

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, playlist, youtube-iframe-api

I can play public playlists just fine in my embedded youtube iframe setup.  I was able to play private playlists, including the Watch Later one, up until a few weeks ago.  I'm using the [Youtube Iframe Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to play and specify the playlist like so:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      ytplayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            videoId: videoID,
            playerVars: {
                'autoplay': 1,
                'modestbranding': 1,
                'rel': 0,
                'autohide': 1,
                'enablejsapi': 1,
                'listType':'playlist', 
                'playlist': 'PLIjo1t8cDbpGhOJrgEgMGFMb-VtAus_x9' // also tried using 'list'
            },
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
      });             
 }
```

When I make the playlist public, it works fine.  When I make it private, it just plays the specified video by itself, and doesn't show the playlist controls.

I'm using Google oAuth, and am currently signed in with it when trying this, though I think when it used to work, it was enough that I was logged into my google/youtube account on any tab in the browser.

Has something changed recently that doesn't allow private playlists to be played in embedded iframes or something?  Or is there a place to give it my access token?

Comment: Does the iframe api know about the browser's state with Google's oAuth?  I also tried looking for any errors that come up when playing a private playlist, and there aren't any.  It just only plays the video you specify and the playlist is null.  Any ideas for things to try?

Comment: I'm noticing a difference between public and private playlists (or working vs non-working) is this error I get in the browser console on private playlists:  `GET https://www.youtube.com/list_ajax?style=json&action_get_list=1&list=PLIjo1t8cDbpGhOJrgEgMGFMb-VtAus_x9 400 (OK)`.  I haven't been able to track that down to anything specific yet, though, if anyone knows what that means.

Comment: I’ve done various tests and only playlists marked as public or unlisted will work; private playlists won’t. Moreover, there doesn’t seem to be any way to change the access of some playlists like *Watch Later*; it’s permanently marked as private. I think they changed it under the (false) assumptions that if the playlist is private, then you’d never need to embed it, and that the *Watch Later* list is personal and nobody would share it. As usual, Google devs are being very narrow-minded and shallow, thinking only of their own use-case scenarios instead of what users actually do, want, and need.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it's not just happening for me.  I agree that if that was the intent, it wasn't thinking broadly enough.